# Regular expression to validate alpha numeric string starting with 3 or 4 having total length max 20

Tags: regex, alphanumeric

Any one can help me for getting an Regular expression to validate alpha numeric string starting with 3 or 4 having total length max 20.

### Valid strings

- 3
- 4
- 3ewwerew
- 4sdf123

### Invalid strings

- sadasd
- 23sdfds

reg ex experts please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Where is your *concrete* problem in writing a regular expression for this? What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is Stackoverflow, not Mechanical Turk.

Comment: Hi team, I had this expression  ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,20}$. I want to bring one more limitation string should start with 3 or 4. I am new regex, that why I need to raise this question in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^[34][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,19}$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oN6vE2/1)